# Sliding a div across the screen using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project where I have a div which shows data that is returned from an AJAX call to PHP.

When the user clicks on something, I want the container div to slide over to the left but for some reason the animation is not working.

Below is my jquery snippet that isn't working:

```
$( "#downloadsContainer" ).animate({
                    position: "absolute",
                    left: "-200px",
                  }, 5000, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                  });
```

When I run the above code, nothing happens, I see no errors in the chrome console.

However, if I run the following code it works just without the animation obviously:

```
$("#downloadsContainer").css({ "position": "absolute", "left": "-200px" });
```

I don't understand what's wrong with the animation and why nothing is happening.

Comment: maybe because "position" is an invalid property to animate? Declare the position in css then just animate left. jquery likes to just not do anything when you run an "invalid" animate.

Comment: I've tried removing position: absolute but nothing happens still, makes no difference

Comment: hmmm, then from this snippet the only other thing I could see is if the selector isn't finding your element... but i'm sure you'd get an error then. If you console.log something in the finished callback does it fire?

Comment: Does it have a left value and position set before you try to animate it, jQuery needs a starting point.

Comment: @adeneo that was the reason, I thought it would be able to get it current left position, I've given it a left and position relative in the css and its working now. Do you want to add it as an answer

Comment: Sure, why not, posting an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's animate needs a starting point, somewhere to animate from, so the left value has to be set before animating, even to zero, as long as it's not `auto`, the default value.

jQuery `css()` doesn't have this issue, it doesn't need a starting point, it just sets the value.

Also, to position an element and make the element actually move, the element **must** have a position other than the default `static` set before animating.